# Clipping surface polygon by a rather nasty large Spatial polygon data frame

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, polygon

I have come across a tricky issue.

I am trying to perfom a simple polygon clip using `sp` package, either using the fuction `st_difference(st_union(x),st_union(y))` (or a variant there of) or `st_intersection`function, whichever works best.

While this is easy with two surface polygons, I need to clip it to a horrible large downloaded Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, its just a shapefile for the UK, downloaded from:
https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

The shapefiles are as as follows (plotted in `leaflet`): 
[image]

```
    > str(uk)
    Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
      ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  70 variables:
      .. ..$ ID_0      : Factor w/ 1 level "242": 1
      .. ..$ ISO       : Factor w/ 1 level "GBR": 1
      .. ..$ NAME_0    : Factor w/ 1 level "United Kingdom": 1
    # .....etc.
    #
    > str(box)
    sfc_POLYGON of length 1; first list element: List of 1
     $ : num [1:5, 1:2] -7.237 0.126 0.126 -7.237 -7.237 ...
     - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "POLYGON" "sfg"
```

I want to clip the `box` (blue) to the `uk`, the reason for this is it takes too long to render the shapefile in of the UK (and france for that matter) in leaflet.

Comment: you're a bit muddled between `sp` and `sf` packages. The functions starting `st_` are from `sf`, and data objects like `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` are from `sp`. So your `box` is from `sf` and your `uk` is from `sp`. You normally cant use ops from one package with data from another without some conversions...

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I am new to both packages and indeed using R for these sorts of applications so all help and tips are welcome. Its only my list (as well as `rgdal` haha) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably do?

```
sf::st_intersection(UK, box)
```

Complete code

```
library(sf)

UK <- readRDS("./gadm36_GBR_0_sf.rds")

#create box since it was not provided in question
box <- c("POLYGON((-7.237 48,0 48,0 52,-7.237 52, -7.237 48))") %>% 
  st_as_sfc(crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

mapview::mapview(list(UK,box))
```

[image]

```
mapview::mapview( st_intersection(UK, box) )
```

[image]

## update

If you want to cut the box with the shapefile of the UK, use `st_difference()`

```
mapview::mapview( st_difference (box, UK) )
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! thanks for your continued help (you have answered another one of my queries). Although I was actually to crop it the other way round, to have the sea component of the box remaining! I am sure I can figure it out unless you have a quick fix! Thanks again

Comment: ignore, got it from you previous comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf3.html haha! Many thanks and excuse my laziness......